# Starting a new game in Elite Dangerous

Tags: elite-dangerous

How do I start a new game in Elite Dangerous? I'm new to the game and I've managed to get myself a long distance from anything. I'm wanting to abandon this game and start again but I can't see how. Start game takes me back in to my current game. I don't have an option for start new game.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can delete your save from the Main Menu, [per the FAQ](https://www.elitedangerous.com/en/faqs):

> To reset your game, go to back to the Main Menu » Options and the Clear Save option will be available. **WARNING**: Selecting this will delete all in-game progress. If you choose to do this, the Create New Player screen will appear and you will be able to choose a new name.

If you just want to reset your position, you can kill yourself. If you die, you get the "Ship Destroyed" screen. This allows you to pay your rebuy cost (5% of the total value of your ship and loadout) to get your old ship back, and you will spawn at the last station that you docked at.

You will also notice another option, "Free Sidewinder". This is a free ship that is always available, in the event that you cannot pay the rebuy costs for your old ship. This free Sidewinder is your starter ship, and choosing this option will spawn you at the starter location. This restarts your ship and location, but keeps your credits, rank, etc...

Comment: I happened to accidentally dock on a fleet carrier and I now I have to start over cuz there are just so much things to do in the starter system...

Answer (score 8):

In the menu on the right, there should be an option to self-destruct, which will spawn you back at the last station you visited.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question. Paul wants to know how to start from scratch, not get back to the last station he visited.

Comment: @Shaun he mentions that he was far away from everything, because it factored into him wanting to restart. Fair to offer this as a solution.

Comment: That would definitely have been a valid option, had I known it was an option.

Comment: @TankorSmash While I agree, I think an answer like this is more appropriate as a comment on his question. The idea here is that these questions and answers should be useful to other people. If someone searches Google for "how to start a new game in Elite: Dangerous", clicks on a link to this question, and reads "Self-destruct to get back to the last station you visited" as the solution, we will not have helped that person at all.